# Getting content of the node having childs via DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, domdocument

I have following html:

```
<html ><body >Body text <div >div content</div></body></html>
```

How could I get content of body without nested `<div>`? 
I need to get 'Body text', but do not have a clue how to do this.

result of running

```
$domhtml = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
print $domhtml->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

is 'Body textdiv content', which is not exactly what I want to get

Comment: assuming your actual HTML is more complex, do you wish to exclude just the text in particular elements? Or do you wish to exclude all text that is not a first child of body?

Comment: @dnagirl: my html is not actually so complex, but I rather wanted to exclude all text that is not a first child of body

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) for problems like this. It's very flexible

```
$domhtml = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domhtml);
$query="/html/body/text()"; //gets all text nodes that are direct children of body

$txtnodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($txtnodes as $txt) {
    echo $txt->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: This works, but shows only text, how to get content with its html ?

Answer (score 4):

```
$domhtml = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
print $domhtml->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->textContent;
```

Comment: did you try it? i'm afraid it does not work as expected. As I recall, DOMNode does not have innerHTML property

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) This should work for you:

```
$domhtml = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html); 
print $domhtml->getElementsByTagName('body')->firstChild->nodeValue;
```