# Am I able to retrieve a node value without the content of its child nodes?

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

I have troubles trying to retrieve the node's value using PHP's DOMDocument. If needed node has some children - node value will contain their content as well.

Example: I have a HTML document with the following content:

```
<div>
  small
  <div id="main_div">
    Main div with a huge content in it
    <div>Subdiv 1</div>
    <div>Subdiv 2</div>
    <div>Subdiv 3</div>
    Tail of the main div
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following PHP script:

```
$site = new DOMDocument();
$site->loadHTML($content);
$divs = $site->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div){
  echo $div->textContent;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

If I try to get node id `main_div` its nodeValue will be equal to:

```
Main div with a huge content in it Subdiv 1 Subdiv 2 Subdiv 3 Tail of the main div
```

Am I able to retrieve only "*Main div with a huge content in it Tail of the main div*" (the content of the `main_div` without its children)?

I have read the question '[Getting content of the node having childs via DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966868/getting-content-of-the-node-having-childs-via-domdocument)' but the accepted answer getting me to the same result: nodes are outputting with the content of their children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside each `div` element are DOMText nodes that contain the actual text. Instead of using `$div->textContent`, collect the nodeValues of each child text node:

```
foreach($divs as $div){
  $text = array();

  foreach ($div->childNodes as $childNode) {
    if ($childNode->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE && $childNode->nodeValue) {
      $text[] = trim($childNode->nodeValue);
    }
  }

  if ($text) {
    print implode(' ', $text) . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alf! It worked! The only problem is that the `#main_div` contents appeared split into two parts. But it can be simply concatenated back.